# Convergence in measure implies integrable.

Tags: real-analysis

$f_n$  converge to $f$ in measure in $E$, and 
$\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\int_E|f_n|\,\mathrm{d}x < ∞$ holds, prove $f$ is Lebesgue integrable in $E$.

I got stuck, thanks for any hint or help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Lebesgue measure is $\sigma$-finite, if a sequence $f_n$ converges in measure to $f$, then there is a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ such that $f_{n_k}\to_k f$ almost-everywhere (thus $f$ is measurable).

$\lvert f\rvert$ is the almost-everywhere limit of the absolute values of the same subsequence. By Fatou's lemma $$\int_E\lvert f\rvert=\int_E\liminf_{k\to\infty}\left\lvert f_{n_k}\right\rvert\le \liminf_{h\to\infty}\int_E\left\lvert f_{n_k}\right\rvert\le \sup_n\int_E\lvert f_n\rvert$$

Comment: Thanks, I got it.