# Convergence in Measure and Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I am trying to solve this problem:
Consider measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$. Also, $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite. Suppose that a sequence of measurable functions $h_n$ converges to $h$ in measure. Assume $h$ is integrable and there exists a finite constant $K$ such that $\int |h_n|d\mu \leq K$ for all $n$. Prove that $g(h_n)$ converges in measure to $g(h)$ for any continuous function $g$.

My try: We can write
\begin{align}
& \mu(\{\omega: |g(h_n)-g(h)|\geq \epsilon\}) \\&=\mu(\{\omega: |g(h_n)-g(h)|\geq \epsilon, |h_n(\omega)-h(\omega)|\geq \delta_m\})+ \mu(\{\omega: |g(h_n)-g(h)|\geq \epsilon, |h_n(\omega)-h(\omega)|\leq \delta_m\})
\end{align}
where $\delta_m$ goes to zero from above. Then, I try to prove that the first term on the RHS is zero because when $m \to \infty$ is basically zero since the set is empty, and the second term on the RHS is also zero due to the fact that $h_n$ converges to $h$ in measure. My problem is I did not use the fact that $\int |h_n|d\mu \leq k$. So, what is the problem of my proof?
Can we prove this using DCT or MCT?

Comment: Suggestions applying to questions like this: First, try to write up your proof formally and carefully, making sure to explicitly write why each statement follows. Second, try to find a counterexample to the problem when you remove one of the conditions (this may or may not exist depending on whether or not the condition is truly necessary) and study how it interacts with each line of your proof

Comment: Note that integrability of $h$ follows from being $\sigma$-finite and having $\sup_{n \in \mathbb N} \int |h_n| < \infty$ as [shown here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2830122/convergence-in-measure-implies-integrable), so that hypothesis is actually superfluous. That leaves less conditions for you to try to break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think integrability has anything to do with this question.

So we have to prove $g\circ h_{n}\rightarrow g\circ h$ in measure. A theorem says that, it is equivalent to show that, for any subsequence $(g\circ h_{n_{k}})$ of $(g\circ h_{n})$, it has a further subsequence $(g\circ h_{n_{k_{l}}})$ such that $g\circ h_{n_{k_{l}}}\rightarrow g\circ h$ a.e.

Now $h_{n}\rightarrow h$ in measure, then so is $h_{n_{k}}\rightarrow h$ in measure, and hence there is a subsequence $h_{n_{k_{l}}}\rightarrow h$ a.e. Then by the continuity of $g$, we have $g\circ h_{n_{k_{l}}}\rightarrow g\circ h$ a.e.